# При открытии SMS через intent вбивать необходимый номер в качестве контакта

Tags: android, android-intent, sms

Мне поручили нетривиальную задачу, связанную с "шерингом" смс, а именно - определенному контакту. Т.е., пользователь вбивает номер на экране, жмет "Отправить через смс" и необходимо по номеру (который вбил пользователь) открыть контакт в смс и отправить ему
Как такое возможно сделать? Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант можно установить данные в интенте:

```
Intent smsIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
smsIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
smsIntent.putExtra("address","your desired phoneNumber");         
smsIntent.putExtra("sms_body","your desired message");
smsIntent.setFlags(android.content.Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(smsIntent);
```

[Вот есть доки](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common#Messaging) по вашему вопросу вот что нужно наверное:

```
sms:<phone_number>
smsto:<phone_number>
mms:<phone_number>
mmsto:<phone_number>
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло )
Хватило добавление в манифест 
<intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
и
 sendIntent.type = "vnd.android-dir/mms-sms"
sendIntent.putExtra("address", "number") в код

Comment: рад что все получилось :)